# Proof of quantum safety of the Merkle signature scheme

Tags: digital-signature, quantum-computing

The [Wikipedia article about the Merkle signature scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_signature_scheme) claims that it is

> very adjustable and resistant against quantum computing.

What proof is there of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Merkle signature scheme is based on a hash tree over one-time signatures, e.g. using [Lamport's scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_signature).

Roughly speaking, both Lamport's scheme and the hash tree are secure as long as the hash function is resistant to preimages and second-preimages. There can be details because when using hash trees, preimage attacks are often *multi-target*, i.e. there are several values for which the attacker would like a preimage, and a preimage for any one of them would yield a success. Yet, preimage resistance still leads the scheme overall robustness.

Against quantum computing, a "perfect" hash function of output size *n* bits still offers resistance *2<sup>n/2</sup>*. E.g. with SHA-256 (a 256-bit output), the best quantum computer would still need *2<sup>128</sup>* operations (i.e. way too many to be feasible, with a huge margin) to break preimage resistance.

(This also means that against *classical* computers, a 256-bit hash function is total overkill when used in Merkle scheme. But, against classical computers, we can also use RSA or ECDSA, which are way more efficient than Merkle's scheme.)